# Laravel syncWithPivotValues almacenando valores

Tags: php, laravel

amigos, estoy teniendo un inconveniente al tratar de almacenar en mi tabla intermedia datos, la situacion es la siguiente, tengo 3 tablas relacionadas: tabla farmacias, tabla productos y tabla farmacia_producto, las relaciones foreign key esta todo bien, ahora estoy tratando de almacenar valores en la tabla farmacia_producto, esta es su estructura:

```
-farmacia_producto:
---id
---farmacia_id
---producto_id
---web
```

desde la vista estoy cargando las farmacias que existen, para ello use unos checkbox:

```
<div class="form-group has-label">
    <label for="farmacias">Farmacias (Puntos de Venta)</label> <br>
    @foreach($farmacias as $farmacia)
        <label for="farmacia">{{ $farmacia->titulo }}</label>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="bootstrap-switch col-3" type="checkbox" value="{{ $farmacia->id }}" data-toggle="switch" name="farmacias[]" {{ in_array($farmacia->id, $producto->farmacias->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'checked' : '' }} data-on-label="<i class='nc-icon nc-check-2'></i>"
                data-off-label="<i class='nc-icon nc-simple-remove'></i>" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="success" />
                <?php $value = ''; ?>
                @foreach ($producto->farmacias as $item)
                    @if ( $item->pivot->farmacia_id == $farmacia->id )
                        <?php $value = $item->pivot->web;  break; ?>
                    @endif
                @endforeach

                <input class="form-control col-9" name="web[]" type="text" value="{{ $value }}" url="true"/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

aqui lo que hago es que me muestre en varios checkbox y inputs las farmacias y su web, para el caso de que sea un editar muestra el checkbox en true y muestra su web. Tambien si notan el checkbox y input lo estoy trabajando como un array, esto debido a que el numero de farmacias regisradas varia, es decir pueden existir 2 o 8  farmacias por ejemplo, pueden ser mas tambien, entonces desde el controlador recibo los datos de la siguiente forma:

```
if (is_array( $request->farmacias )){
    for( $i=0; $i<count($request->farmacias); $i++ ){
        $producto->farmacias()->syncWithPivotValues( [$id, $request->farmacias[$i]] , ["web"=> $request->web[$i]] );
    }
}else{
    $producto->farmacias()->sync(null);
}
```

tomo la longitud del array farmacias, serian las farmacias que esten en "on" o "checked" y voy recorriendo el array farmacias y web, y se lo paso como parametro a `$producto->farmacias()->syncWithPivotValues()` el $id(primer parametro) es el id del producto, tambien valide que en el caso de el array farmacias no exista, es decir no se selecciono ninguna farmacias, aplico lo siguiente `$producto->farmacias()->sync(null);` esto me permite eliminar las farmacias registradas del producto relacionado(solo para el caso de que el producto tenga farmacias registradas),  este para el caso de que quiera editar un producto la cual ya tiene farmacias registradas, entonces al cambiar el estado del checkbox farmacias a off, me eliminara en la tabla farmacia_producto las farmacias relacionadas al producto, actualmente funciona perfectamente.

El error que estoy presentando es que en esta linea:

```
   for( $i=0; $i<count($request->farmacias); $i++ ){
        $producto->farmacias()->syncWithPivotValues( [$id, $request->farmacias[$i]] , ["web"=> $request->web[$i]] );
    }
```

esta sucediendo que no me esta guardando de forma ordenada la informacion que se envia, por ejemplo envio la siguiente informacion:

```
$id = 3 // id producto
farmacias = ['1', '2', '3']
web = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3']
```

en la tabla farmacia_producto me esta almacenando lo siguiente

```
id  |  farmacia_id  | producto_id | web 
1   |      1        |      3      | link3
3   |      3        |      3      | link3
```

como pueden notar el id 2 de farmacia no lo guardo, y en la web esta tomando solo el ultimo link

que estoy haciendo mal?? gracias   de antemano

Comment: al aplicarlo me guarda solo la farmacia 3 con el link3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dice en la documentación de Laravel [Syncing Associations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations):

> If you would like to insert the same intermediate table values with each of the synced model IDs, you may use the `syncWithPivotValues` method

Lo que pasándolo por el traductor de google resulta en:

> Si desea insertar los mismos valores de la tabla intermedia con cada uno de los ID de modelo sincronizados, puede usar el método `syncWithPivotValues`

Pero vos no querés poner el mismo valor en la columna `web` para todos los registros.
Lo que quieres es poner el valor correspondiente a cada id de farmacia.
O sea, si en el request te llega:

```
farmacias: ['1', '2', '3']
web: ['link1', 'link2', 'link3']
```

Quieres que coincida el id de farmacia `1` con `link1`, el id de farmacia `2` con `link2`, y así sucesivamente...

Entonces `syncWithPivotValues` no te va a servir.

Tendrías que ir directamente por `sync`.

Otra vez la documentación:

> You may also use the `sync` method to construct many-to-many associations. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the intermediate table.
> You may also pass additional intermediate table values with the IDs

Y el traductor de google:

> También puede usar el método `sync` para construir asociaciones de muchos a muchos. El método `sync` acepta una matriz de IDs para colocar en la tabla intermedia. Cualquier ID que no esté en la matriz dada se eliminará de la tabla intermedia. Entonces, después de que se complete esta operación, solo existirán las ID en la matriz dada en la tabla intermedia.
> También puede pasar valores de tabla intermedios adicionales con los ID

El ejemplo que ponen:

```
$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);
```

Y lo que sería en tu código:

```
$producto->farmacias()->sync([
    1 => ['web' => 'link1'],
    2 => ['web' => 'link2'],
    3 => ['web' => 'link3'],
]);
```

Finalmente, puedes que mapear los datos del request a un array con la estructura que espera `sync`.
O sea, un array multidimensional donde la clave sea el Id de la farmacia y el valor sea otro array donde la clave es el nombre de la columna y el valor el link correspondiente que te llega en el request:

```
$array = [
    1 => ['web' => 'link1'],
    2 => ['web' => 'link2'],
    3 => ['web' => 'link3'],
];
```

Para luego pasárselo a `sync`:

```
$producto->farmacias()->sync($array);
```

El mapeo lo dejo a tu criterio, podés hacerlo con un `for`, asignado los elementos al array.

Comment: Bro si funciona, eres un genio, el unico inconveniente seria mapear el array, por ejemplo para este caso, los numeros 1, 2 y 3 son los id de las farmacias, y tambien sirven como indice, ese indice se puede trabajar armar a cualquier antojo? por ejemplo que se de el caso que venga de esta forma '$array = [ 3 => ["web" => "link3" ]  ]', pregunto xq si ves el id 3 serviria como indice 3, existirian los indices 1 y 2.

Comment: bro por cierto, mil gracias por la ayuda del metodo `sync` eres un crack

Comment: @Murra Sí, no hay problema con los índices numéricos en los arrays de PHP. Puede haber un índice 3 sin que existan el 0, 1 y 2

Comment: bro! ya lo logre! mil gracias por todo!